# Javascript - regex. I need to replace all non valid characters when building ID's

Tags: javascript, regex

When I create unique ID's on some table rows/cells, I use the data returned from a JSON object to create them.  This works great for standard characters, however, the non valid DOM characters don't work.

What I would like to be able to do is to create a function, to pass the variable to and then return a value which has converted the ID and added backslashes to all relevant characters.

So far I have:

```
    var wsTmpS = fncIdConversion(trim(pData.SUPP_SG_SCOPE_CODE));
```

In the library function I have (with a number of different tries commented out....) :

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
function fncIdConversion(pId ) {
//---------------------------------------------------------
//      return "#" + pId.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\])/g, "\\$1" );
//      pId = pId.toString();
//      return pId.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\])/g, "\\$1" );
//      return pId.replace(/([.*+?^$|(){}\[\]])/mg, "\\$1");
//      pId = pId.replace(/([.*+?^$|(){}\[\]])/mg, "\\$1");

//      pId = pId.replace(/(:|\.|\(\)\[|\])/g, "\\$1");

//      pId = pId.replace(/(\(\))/mg, "\\$1");

//      pId =  pId.replace(/[\(\)\[\]{}'"]/mg, "\\$1");
    var pattern = /[\(\)\[\]{}'"]/mg;
    pId = pId.replace(pattern, "||$1");
    return pId;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to replace with `$1` (which defines the variable resulting from a capture group) you need to *define* that capture group by using parentheses `()`:

```
function fncIdConversion(pId ) {
    var pattern = /([\(\)\[\]{}'"])/mg;
    pId = pId.replace(pattern, "\\$1");
    return pId;
}
```

See a working example here: http://regex101.com/r/zI1qG5